# WiFi Direct can not get established in Nearby api after Factory Reset

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, google-nearby

I am using Nearby api on two android tablets to send files between them. They can connect to each other successfully but after doing a factory reset on both devices (that is how our customers receive the device), WiFi direct cannot be established and it throws  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/misc/wifi/networkHistory.txt (No such file or directory). Then After connecting devices to a WiFi it eventually works. Any idea what to do with this issue?

logcat:
E/WifiNetworkHistory: readNetworkHistory: No config file, revert to default, java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/misc/wifi/networkHistory.txt (No such file or directory)
                                                   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/misc/wifi/networkHistory.txt (No such file or directory)
                                                       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
                                                       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
                                                       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:99)
                                                       at com.android.server.wifi.WifiNetworkHistory.readNetworkHistory(WifiNetworkHistory.java:331)
                                                       at com.android.server.wifi.WifiConfigManager.readNetworkHistory(WifiConfigManager.java:1920)
                                                       at com.android.server.wifi.WifiConfigManager.loadConfiguredNetworks(WifiConfigManager.java:1750)
                                                       at com.android.server.wifi.WifiConfigManager.loadAndEnableAllNetworks(WifiConfigManager.java:458)
                                                       at com.android.server.wifi.WifiStateMachine$SupplicantStartingState.processMessage(WifiStateMachine.java:4860)
                                                       at com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.processMsg(StateMachine.java:980)
                                                       at com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.handleMessage(StateMachine.java:799)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
01-01 13:06:18.868 700-747/? E/IpConfigStore: Error parsing configuration: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/misc/wifi/ipconfig.txt (No such file or directory)

Comment: Can you add a logcat? I'd like to know what is crashing.

Comment: @WilliamHarmon edited my question with logcat, thanks.

Comment: What's the Android OS version (and anything else you can think of, eg. build/model) of these devices? And when it crashes, does this show a dialog box or is it a silent crash?

Comment: @WilliamHarmon it was a silent crash, and the android version was 7.0, build number: RT-1708_20171211